# The difference between "was" and "were"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

What is the difference between:

> You **were** like animal when you play football.
>
> You **was** like animal when you play football.

Comment: Hi Rathish, I'm glad that you don't ignore the guidance :D. The short answer is, *second person(you)* is not affected by number. It always take a plural verb or copular(are/were).

Comment: By the way, *animal* is a countable noun, so it should be "like **an** animal".

Comment: They are both wrong! They both have an incorrect tense shift and need a determiner: "You were like an animal when you played football" _or_ "You are like an animal when you play football". Additionally, the second has 3rd person "was", but it should be 2nd person past "were", or present "are".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You** has the following forms of the verb "to be", either "are"(present simple) or "were"(past simple). Since the time "when you **play** football" doesn't refer to the past, you need the verb in the present simple.
Besides, "animal" is a countable noun and requires an article.

> You **are** like an animal when you play football.